# android.content.res.Resources cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dictionary

I have problem when run my apps

```
package com.esri.android.mapsapp.util;
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class UiUtils {

public static int dipsToPixels(int dips) {
   if (dips == 0) {
      return 0;
   }

   final float scale = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
   return (int) (dips * scale + 0.5f);
}

}
```

> I've tried clean on eclipse (Project -> clean) and  set project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Android Clathpath Container but not working

Can anyone tell me  how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You have required context reference to access resources from non activity class

Answer (score 0):

Required Context reference to access resource from Non-Activity classes :

Define Context reference in class with static to access in static methods :

```
private static Context context;
```

Initialize context in constructor :

```
public UiUtils(Context context){
   this.context=context;
}
```

Use context reference to access resources :

```
public static int dipsToPixels(int dips) {
   if (dips == 0) {
      return 0;
   }
   return (int) (dips * context.getResources().getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```